# Switch Hibernate to iBatis

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, ibatis

Currently we are using Hibernate as Persistent Provider for JPA. Is it possible to change later as iBatis. If we change what are the things I need to consider?

Comment: iBatis doesn't implement JPA, it's just a thin layer between JDBC and your objects. So you will probably need to rewrite all you DB accessing code.

Comment: I hope i can reuse JPA entities and it annotations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely you don't want to use already graved iBatis, but maybe [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/core/index.html).

As you see from the documentation, concept is quite different from JPA and Hibernate.
You cannot reuse:

- mappings for entities
- JPQL queries.
- any setup

What you can partially reuse, is entities (only code without jpa mappings) and native queries (queries itself, not annotations).